# Sprinkler Controller Wiring (Power)

Tags: wiring

I bought a new Rachio 2 controller and the power has black, white, and ground wires but there are only black and ground coming from my electrical box. My old controller (Irritrol) had the black and white together. If I do that again, put the  2 blacks and white together, will that be ok?

[image: Left is from the electrical box, right is inside the controller.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is mains 120V wiring, then that is a flexible conduit or a wire whip where someone stole the neutral wire.  Maybe they needed some pigtails.

You can buy some white THHN wire by-the-foot and fish it down the pipe.  The other two wires are THHN *stranded*, so I would get that (it's also easier to work with).  Given how flexible stranded wire is, might as well get #12 even if the others are #14. Can't hurt, might help.

If this is low-voltage wiring for the sprinklers, then all bets are off, but using green as a *first choice* for DC power is unfortunate.  Normally red is + and black is -, with other colors used to disambiguate as needed, and green usually gets chosen as a 4th or 5th color.

Answer (score 1):

The existing wiring has the wrong color for neutral, which should be white, not green. Check it out at the upstream junction box. I recommend running a dedicated white neutral wire too.

Once you’ve done that, connect color-to-color: black for hot, white for neutral, green for safety ground.

If you’re unsure about this, consider hiring an electrician.

EDIT: should be migrated to DIY.

Comment: This is correct. Whoever installed it before did it wrong. Now is the time to fix it.

Comment: The answer is correct there should be a neutral and the circuit should be GFCI protected since outside. Power without a ground in a damp/ wet area is not safe.+

Comment: Ok, thank you all for the feedback!! I will most likely hire an electrician, but if the ground is actually neutral, how did it work before with my old controller?

Comment: @Jeff Ground is never neutral.  Neutral is not ground.  Ground is a safety feature to arrest dangerous misguided currents. Neutral is the normal path of current return. If you try to combine them, you defeat ground altogether.

Comment: @Harper the comments above state that the ground wire is actually the neutral wire and is colored incorrectly. So, my question is how did it work with the previous controller. Sounds like there may have been know ground before then.

Comment: Then where's ground? @Jeff ... No, this is ground all right.  They are intentionally bootlegging neutral off ground.  That should be corrected.

Comment: @Harper, thanks I called an electrician and had them add a neutral wire. Appreciate all the help!